# Umbraco is not displaying image in template with media picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco7

I am using media picker property editor in template to display image. The problem is that I can't see image on page but I can see alt tag. Additionally, I can see values in debugging.

```
  @{
    var teamGroupPhoto = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("teamGroupPhoto");
    if (teamGroupPhoto != null)
     {
    <img class="img-responsive" src="@teamGroupPhoto.Url" alt="Groupphoto"/>
     }
   }
```

**Screenshot of code in VS:**
[image]

**when I browse link of image in media folder in Umbraco backoffice i get IIS error:**
[image]

Comment: Do you see the preview of the image in the umbraco backoffice?

Comment: No I don't see preview of image in Umbraco i get HTTPerror 404.4 Not found.

Comment: What about the configuration of iis? are you using iis express?